# Draw behind navigation bar but not status bar

Tags: android

I want my fragment to be shown behind the navigation bar (which I set to transparent), but not behind the status bar. What flag do I need to set? I am currently setting the following:

```
            activity?.window?.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
            activity?.window?.navigationBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
            view?.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
```